# Set dynamic id to i18n attribute

Tags: angular

what i want to achive is that the value of that i18n attribute be equals to "@@menu.itemName", right now it takes all as a string "@@menu.{{item.name}}". Im not sure why it don't parse the js code

```
<div i18n="@@menu.{{item.name}}">{{item.name}}
```

```
<trans-unit id="menu.itemName">
...
</trans-unit>
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

i18n supports only strings I believe, so you can't assing it an object like you are trying to.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).